# How do you tell where your cursor is when using a Wacom tablet?

Tags: drawing-tablet

I'm considering purchasing a tablet with no screen that connects to your monitor. Questions like [this](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/18094/can-you-see-while-drawing-on-the-drawing-tablet) explained that this is no problem because after all, you don't need to look at your mousepad to draw with a mouse. But a mouse stops drawing when you stop clicking. How do you keep your pen from drawing a pencil mark when you touch it to the pad to find out where the cursor is?

Comment: (Disclaimer: I don't have a tablet) Why do you need to know where it is? You can just draw with it in the location that you want since it's always mapped to the same part of the screen

Comment: Imagine trying to draw a line connecting the center of two circles. A mouse allows me to move precisely to the pixel that is in the center before I start drawing. Trying to do that just by feel for how the tablet maps to the screen, sounds as difficult as doing it on paper without looking at the paper at all.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't need to touch the pen to the tablet to see where the cursor is. Touching the pad will always draw but you can move the cursor around by hovering your pen just above (without actually touching) the tablet.

Honestly it is no problem at all and once you get used to it you can use it instead of a mouse completely. I know people who will use it for normal everyday use like browsing the Internet, checking emails, everything.

Comment: Would you say buying a normal non-touch-no-active-pen containing laptop with wacom tablet against buying a active-pen containing laptop as the value for money? Thank you!